# Cancelling animation state on click of separate div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a set of cards, and some CSS animations that occur when the user clicks the card.I am happy with the results, but i have a problem: if I click a card, it animates and reveals extra content. If I click on it again, it reverts to its simplified state. If I click a card, and then click another without "closing" the previous card, they both stay animated. how can I make it so that when I click on a card, all other cards revert to their un-animated state? 
HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--HEADER-->
    <div class="header">
      <div id="info">
        <p>Current Page</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--CARDS-->
    <ul id="cardList" class="cards">
      <li><div class="card transform">
        <div class="face"><h2>: )</h2></div>
          <div id="containText">
            <h3>HI! I am a card.</h3><br>
            <p>Click me to trigger the animation.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="extra">
            <p>Here is some extra info about the items on this card, such as stuff,                    things and blah.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="disappear">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim                    veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea                commodo consequat.</p>
          </div>
          </div>
      </li>
      <li><div class="card transform">TWO</div></li>
      <li><div class="card transform">THREE</div></li>
      <li><div class="card transform">FOUR</div></li>
      <li><div class="card transform">FIVE</div></li>
      <li><div class="card transform">SIX</div></li>
    </ul>

    <!--FOOTER-->
    <div class="footer"></div>
  </body>
```

CSS:

```
body
{
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  font-family: "arial";
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header p
{
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 12px;
  color: white;
}

/* APP BARS SECTION */
.header
{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #d36363;
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 6px #888888;
  z-index: +1;
}

.footer
{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #d36363;
  box-shadow: 0px -6px 6px #888888;
}

/* CARDS SECTION */
.cards
{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 60px;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: -1;
}

.cards li
{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.card
{
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  left: -5%;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #686868;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* CARDS CONTENT SECTION */
#containText
{
  position: absolute;
  width: 76%;
  color: #58a7dd;
  top: -2px;
  left: 90px;
  text-align: justify;
}

#containText p
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
}

.face
{
  position: relative;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  border: solid #58a7dd;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #58a7dd;
}

.face h2
{
  position: relative;
  left: 3px;
  top: 20px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.extra
{
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  top: 7px;
  margin: auto;
  color: #2f4f4f;
}

.disappear
{
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  height: 40%;
  top: 5px;
  margin: auto;
  color: #2f4f4f;
  opacity: 0;
}

.appear
{
  animation: appear 1.2s ease;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes appear
{
  0%
  {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100%
  {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.transform
{
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.transform-active
{
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 6px #888888;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(".card").click(function()
{
  $(this).toggleClass("transform-active");
  $(".disappear", this).toggleClass("appear");
});
```

Working demo: https://codepen.io/BGGrieco/pen/PjOevR

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea: Iterate over all elements having class "card" attached and then reset their actual class before assigning the new class to the clicked card?

```
$(".card").click(function()
{
  // Reset all cards
  $(".card").each(function(){
     $(this).removeClass("transform-active");
     $(this).addClass("transform");

     // Reset their children with class "appear" as well
     $(this).children(".appear).each(function(){
       $(this).removeClass("appear");
       $(this).addClass("disappear");
     }
  });

  // Now set transform-active to the clicked card ...
  $(this).addClass("transform-active");
  $(this).removeClass("transform");

  // ... and all of its children with class "disappear" as well
  $(this).children(".disappear).each(function(){
     $(this).addClass("appear");
     $(this).removeClass("disappear");
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this does not seem to work.

Comment: I placed my earlier code snippet into your existing code which should work now as expected. If not I didn't get your question...

Comment: My bad, it does work. My problem now is applying the same effect to the content of the card, the ".disappear" element.

Comment: I'm still not sure if my edited answer fits your needs now, but if you read the comments, you should be able to adapt the solution to do what you want.
Maybe try to be clearer in your question next time to get a quicker solution. ;-)

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply. No you understood perfectly what I am trying to do, its just that I don't think I understood your code. Your comments helped greatly, but it still has problems: atm, once a card is clicked all of them are triggered and if clicked again they remain triggered. I am experimenting with it. You can see what's going on here, if you are interested: https://codepen.io/BGGrieco/pen/PjOevR and thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Simply store the previous, then hide that on click:

```
var previous;

$(".card").click(function(){
  if(previous) 
     $(previous).removeClass("transform-active");

  if(previous !== this) 
     $(this).addClass("transform-active");

  previous = this;
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Jonas w, your answer works great but it leaves me in the dark as to how to manage the ".disappear" class. I am trying to experiment with your solution, but at the moment ".disappear" does not get reset upon clicking another card.